# Mysql 5.6/5.7: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, subquery, create-view

MySql Create view:

```
CREATE VIEW Foo as 
select type from (select 8 as type UNION ALL select 9 as type) types;
```

MySql 5.7.11 on windows: works, but mysql 5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 (Ubuntu): not working.

```
View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
```

This is a change from 5.6 to 5.7?  I tried to upgrade mysql to 5.7 on Ubuntu, but it is not available on Ubuntu.  Any advice? Thanks.

EDIT: The example is a test case. Real case is to create a view that make one record of Bar to be two records in the view:

```
   CREATE VIEW Foo as 
    select types.type, bar.value from 
    (select 8 as type UNION ALL select 9 as type) types, Bar bar
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that You're making a view with query that selects from another query.

So You should simply write select query in Your view different way.

Solution:

The query:

```
select type from (select 8 as type UNION ALL select 9 as type) types;
```

is same as:

```
select 8 as type UNION ALL select 9 as type
```

so create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW Foo AS
  select 8 as type UNION ALL select 9 as type;
```

Comment: Thanks. any solution for the real example just added?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a change in MySQL.

Earlier versions of MySQL do not allow inline views (or, derived tables in the MySQL parlance) within a stored view definition.

As far as advice... there doesn't appear to be any need for an inline view in the view query. Beyond that, I'm questioning the need for... that is, the reason that a stored view definition is needed.